# Wget -A Filtering Both By Extension and Filename - Should Be Only By Extension

Tags: wget

I am trying to download all JAR files from the Maven repository.

I type:

wget -A jar -r http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/

It only traverses directories with jar in the filename like "FindJar" and skips all the rest.

It should be traversing all directories until it finds a jar file to download.

Why is it not working that way???

Answer (score 2):

Use FTP access instead:

`wget -A jar -m -l inf ftp://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/`

This will still create the directory hierarchy of the maven website / ftp site.

If you want to download everything without recreating the subdirectories then you can add `-nd` before the URL. This means "no directories".

`wget -A jar -m -l inf -nd ftp://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/`

Answer (score 1):

do `-A *.jar` instead of `-A jar` so wget will look for all files with `.jar` suffix instead of files named `jar`.